# At what radius does general relativity fail and how could we test it?

Tags: general-relativity

It is usually said that general relativity predicts its own down-fall at the point where a spacetime singularity is formed.

However, suppose there is a limit (in distance) in the shrinking of any star/black hole where general relativity does indeed fail. How could we guess that General Relativity is wrong during e.g. a gravitational collapse or gravitational phenomena?

Remark: I guess that possible answers are in the rate of gravitational wave emission, the black hole shadow (not sure), gravitational lensing extra effects in strong fields, echoes from black holes, the detection of neutron stars/white dwarf stars with masses not allowed by General Relativity, orbits not following GR predictions, quasi-normal modes in black holes with anomalous features, and other anomalies from GR. However, I can not guess if some of these could indeed point out the exact distance scale where GR fails. And I mean giving a number or prediction and not only a "range in parameters". References would also be useful.

Comment: Are you current with the Big Bang model of cosmology? Its timeline shows at what time after the BB  GR has to be modified with quantized gravity. The observational data require it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang

Comment: @annav I know the Big Bang model, but as far as I know, there is no clear site where GR could go "wrong". Of course at Planck time or lesser GR is not valid, but when GR leaves to be a good effective theory? At QCD phase transition? Before of that? At dark ages? To my knowledge, there is no specific time (beyond Planck era/inflation era-with careful maybe applicable there too) where GR should not apply in principle. Or should it?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to say at what scale quantum gravity effects become significant without an actual quantum gravity theory. ;) But in supernova BH formation we *expect* that GR is adequate down to the Planck scale, give or take a few orders of magnitude (i.e., much smaller than a proton).